# Eclipse is using too much memory and what is the best configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, grails

What I want is the lightest possible version eclipse so that it consumes as low memory as possible when running. Does any one know how to configure eclipse to be as light as possible?

Currently I am using Eclipse STS but I want to ditch it because it uses average 1 GB memory by itself when not running my projects. I am using 64 bit linux platform.

I just do plain Java/Groovy/Grails and Scala web application development and also Javascript debugging HTML/CSS. I am not using any heavy weight application servers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- remove all unnecessary plugins
- you can change -Xmx in eclipse ini

look at this question: [Getting a lightweight installation of Java Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992749/getting-a-lightweight-installation-of-java-eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

The Scala plugin uses a lot of RAM. The recommended settings for Eclipse with the Scala IDE are described here:

http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/wiki/Setup

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu, I observed a problem with some machines and Ubuntu 64bit causing the machines to consume a lot of RAM.

Comment: That's an interesting observation, but it doesn't actually answer the question.